# How to identity customer orders by customer IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

Say for example I have table Customer and I have another table called orders. How to identify that each order belongs to that particular customer.

Comment: If you have customer (id?) in orders then easily if not then impossible.

Comment: Sounds like you need a foreign key in one table, a primary key in the other, and a foreign key constraint between the two. Which database system are you using?

Comment: You only need to pass id of customer table as foreign key in orders table.

Comment: okay so the foreign key of ID order linked to customer ID will help to justify which row belongs to which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use The Foreign Key On Order Table Of Customer Id

Visit This Link How To Add Foreign Key in Table-

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

and Write Query like `Select * from Order_table where Customer_Id='1'`

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of a **one-to-many** relationship. To implement that you have to use a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) on the **many** side of the relationship to link to the **one** side.

In your case, `Customer` is the **one** side and `Order` is the **many** side, as there could be many orders linking to the same customer.

You will have to add a `customer_ID` column on your `Order` table so it links to the ID column in the `Customer` table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store customer ID in orders table as foreign key.